# Automatic selection of next panel JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Is there any automatic selection option for Hour 2 panel at run time after  Hour 1 attendance is marked (I am using `JTabbedPane`).

[This is my JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhrPn.png)

Comment: I think setSelectedIndex() Works for it !!

Comment: Automatic? No. If there were all these sorts of things, why would they bother paying us the big bucks? Implement a Swing based `Timer`, mark it as 'no repeat' then when it fires, change tabs.

Comment: I mean after adding Hour1 Attendance Hour2 Panel must got selection !! Thats all ! not compleate automatic !! setSelectedIndex() is working !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex-int-) and [JTabbedPane#getSelectedIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getSelectedIndex--). Just set the selected index to `selectedIndex + 1` but make sure to check if the new index isn't out of bounds (`JTabbedPane#getTabCount`).